# SQL count query help

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns and one stores the users ip address. I want to query, but want to restrict it so that users with their ip in the ip_address column are only counted once. Here is my current query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles where article_id = '1'
```

Comment: Look at the `GROUP BY` clause for MySQL. Also, ask programming questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I would use `GROUP BY` over `DISTINCT` as `GROUP BY` allows you to specify which columns you want unique values. Although `DISTINCT` appears to be a function call on a column, it's not - it tries to make each row unique rather than just what you specify.

Comment: @bitxwise - You would like to use a Phillips screwdriver instead of a Torx? `Distinct` and `Group By` serve completely different purposes. OP just wants to count unique ip addresses once

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Notice that there are answers below, 1 using `DISTINCT` and 1 using `GROUP BY`. I was merely giving the OP a direction on which (I think) is the way to go. Unless I misunderstood his question =)

Comment: @bitxwise: So far I cannot see your point in trying to compare `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` for this particular problem. If the OP wanted a *list* of unique IPs, then the answers with `DISTINCT` and those with `GROUP BY` would most probably look very similar. You might say, it's because both of them modify SELECT. But of the two only DISTINCT can also be used to modify COUNT, and count is what the OP wants. With GROUP BY you would just have to resort to subselecting, an unnecessary option here, I think.

Comment: @Andriy: OP didn't mention other cols or constraints in the table. Say the table has UserName, IP - it's possible to have MyUser1 with multiple IP addresses and MyUser2 with a NULL IP address. By the way the question was asked, where users are only considered once if their IP addresses are in the IP column (the "PER IP constraint" that was asked for clarification has yet to be confirmed), the simple `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP)` could yield the "wrong" answer. For example, say the OP wants MyUser1 to only count ONCE despite the multiple IP addresses?

Comment: @Andriy: You guys have assumed you know not only what the OP is asking (w/o clearly established constraints, if any) but also the OP's data. cyberkiwi already asked for clarification as far as whether OP is just looking for a list of unique IP addresses for each article, so I didn't repeat the question. Nevertheless, without clarification I didn't want to make the assumption so I simply gave a direction and explained why I would use one over the other.

Comment: @Andriy: Then depending on what the OP really wants, he/she can decide which to use. Because I was only giving a direction, I posted it as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @bitxwise: Your points about identifying users are valid by all means and the OP may hopefully consider them to possibly improve their design for this and maybe other tables. But I can see not even hint about any other way to identify the users but by ip address. Also, it has been stated quite clearly that the table has three columns. Now, one is `article_id`, the other has to be `ip_address`. What then do you think should be the third column in a table called `articles`?

Comment: @Andriy: The question could be  could be "how many times an article was viewed, only counting each IP once" or it could be "how many users viewed the article, only counting each user once as long as their IP was captured and regardless of how many IP addresses were captured for each user". As for what the 3rd column should be, well, it COULD be UserName - IP address shouldn't even be in a table called Articles if you ask me =) Really, the table could/should be called ArticleAccess or something...?

Comment: @Andriy: I honestly don't know enough about the OP's data / schema, and really, neither do the rest of us. Your last comment is more or a less just another assumption...for all we know the 3rd column could even be DateAccessed. Say users have to pay to view articles so it would not be right for a user to view the same article from different IP addresses at the same time (i.e. shared accounts) and say the OP is trying to find "delinquent accounts". Just a possibility =)

Comment: @bitxwise: I think the answers given are only to the point. It's the comments that contain assumptions. But many of them can be dismissed, as the question actually contains enough details, as I have already shown.

Comment: @Andriy: The OP only posted details on what he/she's looking for _technically_, but not the _business reason_. And typically, result set data is useless w/o known intent or purpose. Perhaps you missed my "delinquent accounts" possibility comment above. But we should stop "spamming" the poor guy's question haha

Comment: @bitxwise: Agree, it's only wise to stop. :) And thanks for taking the initiative, because at the rate you were producing your arguments I just couldn't bring myself to it until responding to all of them, and my English wouldn't let it be as fast.

Answer (score 5):

You want to count unique ip addresses?  Use count(distinct)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP_address) FROM articles where article_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, here is what a solution with GROUP BY might look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT IP_address FROM articles GROUP BY IP_address WHERE article_id = '1')
```

I only post it so others could compare it to the better solution [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895018/sql-count-query-help/4895167#4895167) that uses COUNT(DISTINCT IP_address) and see how one is different from the other.

If there is a better way to use GROUP BY for the same task, I am yet to learn it.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(IP) FROM ARTICLES WHERE ARTICLE_ID = '1' GROUP BY IP
```

Comment: He didn't ask for a list of how many times each IP address viewed an article, but how many times an article was viewed, only counting each IP once.

Comment: Opps, my bad... Anyways, it's answered now

Comment: Well it could be "how many times an article was viewed, only counting each IP once" or it could be "how many users viewed the article, only counting each user once as long as their IP was captured and regardless of how many IP addresses were captured for each user" - OP has yet to clarify =)